# Genymotion shell is there a command to view my database?

Tags: android, shell, genymotion

Hi i am pretty struggling on trying to view my databases that I create from my android code. I am using a genymotion emualator and I cant see anything from the filemanager in my project's data folder. Is there any way to view my database from the genymotion shell ? Thanks.

Comment: Does your adb shell run as root or as shell on that device?  If it runs as root, then `adb pull` or the DDMS file explorer should be able to get it.  If not it's much trickier.  This general question has been asked many times here so you might have a look at the answers to the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always pull it off the device and view it with the [Sqlite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) in Firefox:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/yourdb.db
```

Comment: best answer for me, works like charm on actual genymotion versions.

Answer (score 6):

You can install an app in your emulator which lets you browse installed apps for databases. Root must be available, and since Genymotion virtual devices are rooted, you can follow the next steps:

1. Start your Genymotion virtual device.
2. Download [SQLite Debugger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin) APK using any [APK downloader service](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/).
3. Drag&drop the downloaded APK file to your already running Genymotion virtual device.
4. Start SQLite Debugger in your emulator and select the option "App".
5. A popup appears with all the installed apps. Select one, then view, update or delete its database.

[image: SQLite Debugger showcase]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with via shell either but the following procedure helped me see the database

1.Download a good file browser(I used -- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree)

1. Go to you application from /data/data/(PACKAGE NAME)/databases/(YOUR FILE)

Comment: This is unlikely to work, unless the application has made its own data directory world readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull database from device using adb command

```
adb pull /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/yourdb.db
```

it will be copied to folder where your terminal is pointing to.