# SQL Database Error : Table has no column name

Tags: java, android, mysql

I've gone through a lot of the forum answers and usually the problem is not 
adding a "," or a space where it should be, that will change the SQL statement into something it's not supposed to be.

I tried taking a look at mine and I still can't find the error in my onCreate. And I use Genymotion to emulate the app each time so it can't be that the emulator has a previous database version, so it shouldn't be a problem with the onUpgrade method.

Here's the logcat

```
09-19 07:54:26.137    7344-7344/com.example.cartermah.mywishlist E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table wishes has no column named content
09-19 07:54:26.137    7344-7344/com.example.cartermah.mywishlist E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting content=jalksjldk title=HIHI recorddate=1442663666139
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table wishes has no column named content (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO wishes(content,title,recorddate) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
            at data.DatabaseHandler.addWishes(DatabaseHandler.java:67)
            at com.example.cartermah.mywishlist.MainActivity.saveToDB(MainActivity.java:53)
            at com.example.cartermah.mywishlist.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:15)
            at com.example.cartermah.mywishlist.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 07:54:26.137    7344-7344/com.example.cartermah.mywishlist V/Wished saved!﹕ yeah
```

And the database handler code is

```
package data;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.cartermah.mywishlist.MainActivity;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import model.MyWish;

/**
 * Created by CarterMah on 14/09/2015.
 */
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public final ArrayList<MyWish> wishList = new ArrayList<>();


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //This is where the table is created

        String CREATE_WISHES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Constants.KEY_ID +
                " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + Constants.TITLE_NAME + " TEXT, " + Constants.CONTENT_NAME +
                " TEXT, " + Constants.DATE_NAME + " LONG" + ");";



        db.execSQL(CREATE_WISHES_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);

        //Create a new table

        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addWishes (MyWish wish) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, wish.getTitle());
        values.put(Constants.CONTENT_NAME, wish.getContent());
        values.put(Constants.DATE_NAME, java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());

        db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        Log.v("Wished saved!","yeah");


        db.close();

    }

    // Get all wishes

    public ArrayList<MyWish> getWishes() {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID,
                            Constants.TITLE_NAME, Constants.CONTENT_NAME, Constants.DATE_NAME,},
                    null, null, null, null, Constants.DATE_NAME + " DESC");


        // loop through cursor to get every row of data

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do{

                MyWish wish = new MyWish();
                wish.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME)));
                wish.setContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME)));

                java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                String dataData = dateFormat.format(new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.DATE_NAME))).getTime());


                wish.setRecordDate(dataData);

                wishList.add(wish);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }



            return wishList;

    }

}
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wishdb";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "wishes";
    public static final String TITLE_NAME = "title";
    public static final String CONTENT_NAME = "content";
    public static final String DATE_NAME = "recorddate";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";


}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.cartermah.mywishlist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import data.DatabaseHandler;
import model.MyWish;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText title;
    private EditText content;
    private Button saveButton;
    private DatabaseHandler dba;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dba = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

        title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        content = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wishEditText);
        saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveToDB();
            }
        });






    }

    private void saveToDB() {

        MyWish wish = new MyWish();
        wish.setTitle(title.getText().toString().trim());
        wish.setContent(content.getText().toString().trim());

        dba.addWishes(wish);
        dba.close();

        // clear the form once users click the save button.

        title.setText("");
        content.setText("");

       // Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WishDetailActivity.class);
       // startActivity(i);

    }


}
```

Comment: try after using `varchar` instead of `TEXT` for `content` in `CREATE_WISHES_TABLE`

Comment: Just tried it. Nothing changes. I still get the same error.

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql? Did you try logging the table creation query in onCreated? Why not pull down the database and see what the table really looks like. That error says your table isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: You can try to dump the database to see if the structure is correct. See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825335/genymotion-shell-is-there-a-command-to-view-my-database. It could be usefull

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id when you insert because id is not autoincrement.OR make id autoincrement.

Comment: Just tried it. Nothing changes. I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you added the column "content" after creating the database for the 1st time?

Answer (score 0):

You mention using Genymotion as a reason an existing DB wouldn't be a problem but I don't think that's an accurate assumption. Unless you are completely uninstalling the app before you launch the new one the previous database version is still on the device and won't be overriden. I would recommend completely uninstalling the app from Genymotion and then install it with the latest onCreate statement and see if a fresh install would overwrite any possible occurrence of a previous database version.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problems, but All I've done is just to uninstall the apps and reinstall again, it's worked perfectly.